# Javascript setting variables and object and proper syntax (debug console)

Tags: javascript, function, object, declaration, invoke

So I am trying to invoke methods on a page and I know the values that I want to put inside the methods but I can't seem to get the syntax to work. I feel so, well.. lamerized.

Ok so here is the javascript method on the page

```
function ReturnValue (sValue, sText) 
{
     window.focus();
     var oForm = document.EditForm;

     switch (szType)        // Form element name
     {
     case 'agt':
        oForm.agt.value = sText;
        oForm.agentman.value = sValue;
        oForm.agtid.value = sValue;                              
        oForm.getagt.focus();
        break;

     case 'county':     
        oForm.County.value = sValue;
        sCurrentCounty = new String(sValue);
        document.all("CountyDisp").innerHTML = sText;
        document.all("City").value = "";
        document.all("CityDisp").innerHTML = "";
        document.all("Area").value = "";
        document.all("AreaDisp").innerHTML = "";
        break;
   default:
        break;      
     }  // End switch
 return;
}
```

Very straight forward function and you would assume that the parameters were strings, right?
So in the IE8 Script Debugger Console I tried this:

> ReturnValue("adf","asdf");
>   //FAIL
>     "Object expected"

Object expected huh, well maybe I need single quotes for the strings I assumed next (just in case).

> ReturnValue('adf','asdf'); //FAIL
>     "Object expected"

Okay, just making sure.. So I need an object that stores a string. How about using a var I thought..

> var o = "adf"; var p = "dfsa"; ReturnValue(o,p); //FAIL "Object expected"

I tried with single quotes just to be sure. So after all that I am sure an object is needed. So I tried to create an Object.

> o = new Object(); k = new Object(); //{...}

Now I from here I didn't know how to add a string to an object so I just did this.

> o.value = "text"; k.value = "field";  // "text" ... "field"

Okay so now I am feeling excited I have an object with some string in there so now I try to put it all together again.

> ReturnValue(o,z)
>     // EPIC FAIL "Object expected"

I am putting Objects in there! Now I'm back to square one, can someone help?

Okay problem still not solved.

Upon further investigation I found that the script does infact run once at the very beginning of the page load. I can debug and break and while its paused through the code I can run the methods. But after I release and it finishes declaring all the variables I can't run any methods. But, for some reason the same method that I am trying to run is able to run from a Popup using the Window.Opener.ReturnValue(string,string);

I dont get it!

Javascript guru's where are you when I need you!

Comment: Ok I am still working on this and have had a break through. It turns out that if I type anything like 

Adfasdf()

I'll get the same Error;

For some reason the code isn't loading into the Console debugger. x_x I don't know why?

Comment: Post the whole <script> block.

Comment: So I was wondering why you started so many sentences with "so"?

Comment: Here's the full script in question  

[http://www.dailynewstube.com/script.txt][1]

Comment: @Proximo, it's poor grammar. It's similar to starting a sentence with "but" in that there's almost never a valid usage. Not everyone on international forums use English as their first language so you should at least try and use the language correctly.

Comment: @Nick, I'm really not concerned with grammar at this point. You're just looking at things from a negative perspective. Had a bad day? Look at it this way, someone who doesn't speak English very well would learn the power of so. I included several mini snippets of code so that should help the English impaired. Learn proper etiquette because you're looking like a stuck up British wanker who has a problem with carefree Americans. If you aren't going to attempt to answer questions please refrain from commenting. 
Good day ol'boy.

Comment: Actually, I had no idea of your nationality - but it's the first time I've seen racism on here. Learn English up to high school level and lose the racism and we may get on just fine.

Comment: Racism? I didn't bring up race. Are you dillusional? I just don't understand why you would comment on someone totally unrelated to my problem. Anyway, problem solved, beat it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've defined szType somewhere else, I pasted this function into a scratch page and played around with it and I can't reproduce this issue in IE8 (or FireFox 3).

Googling around, the only thing I found was a reference saying that if you set the script type incorrectly you might get this as IE won't parse the script block at all. Is your script block set as "text/javascript"?

If that doesn't work, can you provide more of the code involved (perhaps the markup too)?

On another note, you might want to look at using something like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or one of the other JS libraries. Browser-specific JS like this is evil (death to document.all).

Comment: Thanks for the google search on this. Yeah I think you are right. This is the tag:

<script LANGUAGE="javascript"> 

This isn't my page so I have no way of really changing this.

Comment: Yeah, so I can get the 'Object expected' error when I use a <script type="application/javascript">...</script> block. So what appears to be happening here is that your <script> block isn't being parsed at all. The function doesn't exist to IE.

Comment: Funny that it works in the actual IE8 browser but not while debugging -_-

Answer (score 1):

What's the value of szType? I can't see it being set anywhere, maybe that's what it is bombing on? Also, those document.all and form. probably won't work in anything other than IE. document.getElementById('theid') is much better for retrieving dom elements.

Also, can you try setting a breakpoint on the ReturnValue function and step through it? I haven't used the IE8 console this way, but I know you can debug that way.

**edit** Is it able to execute functions that way? Maybe comment out *everything* in ReturnValue and make sure it can actually execute the function itself. You might have to be in a debug session, or invoke the function via window.ReturnValue

Comment: Yeah, you're definitely on to something. I noticed that the code wasn't executing just now. I have it in debug session to no avail. I'm just going to have to fool around with this some more.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps szType, one of oForm, oForm.agt etc is null?

Comment: Yeah I thought of that just after posting this question and set it to 'County' but still nothing.